# Customize AWS Elasticbeanstalk EC2 logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, customization

I'm looking for an option to customize AWS elastibeanstalk logs.
When clicking on the download link in elasticbeanstalk console, the logs needs to be opened in a new tab.

Comment: Can you clarify what's the issue with the link?

Comment: Yes, curerntly the logs are getting downloaded. These logs needs to be opened in a new tab instead of downloading.

Comment: You can't do this, as the files downloaded are zipped. This is how EB console works. But you can stream your logs from EB instance into CloudWatch Logs. Maybe this would be better?

Comment: Yeah I understand and agree with you, when we select option as full logs it is downloading as zip file. But when we select as "last 100 lines", i am looking option to open this in new tab.

Comment: Yes. That's how it works. There is no option to change this sadly.